# Airflow running in multiple containers in ECS. An easy/elegante way of sharing DAGS between all the airflow-components?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

We have Airflow running in ECS in multiple components.

I was feeling curious about how people solve the problem of sharing/updating Dags easily because all these airflow-components need to share the dag files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend everyone Git-sync running as sidecar containers (each component has their own Git-sync side container sharing DAGs with the components via shared volume). It has a number of advantages and "enterprise" features (DAG history in Git, Code review possibility, integration with CI, change auditing, atomic updates of DAGs and their dependencies, you name it)

There are also people who prefer to use EFS volume when using Amazon. This works, but IMHO has some drawbacks (sometimes slower when you have many DAGs, lack of atomic updates for multiple files etc) and in any serious deployment you will have to implement many of the features I mentioned above anyway.

With Git as single source of truth and all the tools available to manage code (DAGs ARE effectively code) Git-Sync is far better and complete solution IMHO.

Comment: does gitsync work with ECS/Fargate or is it only supported in a k8s env?  I cant seem to find a solid answer.

Comment: gitsync is a go binary, and it has a docker container to run. Did you try it? Did it not work in one of the environments you mentioned? Did you have any problems with it? The easiest way if you do not see an answer is to try it.

Comment: The OP asked specifically about an ECS env and you answered with a very specific solution. I assumed you knew if the solution actually worked in the env OP worked in.

Comment: Why do you think it would not @odonry ?